# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' (I put in values 3, 4 , -2)

Tags: python

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' (I put in values 3, 4 , -2)

```py
def main():
    print("This program finds the real solutions to a quadratic")

    a, b, c = input("Please enter the coefficients (a, b, c): ").split(",")

    disc = float(pow(b*b - 4*a*c,0.5))
    
    root1 = float((-b + disc)/(2 * a))
    
    root2 = float((-b - disc)/(2 * a))

    print("The solutions are:" ,root1, root2)
                    
main()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your splitting the three values `a`, `b`, and `c` are still strings. You can convert them to integers with `int(value)` or to floats with `float(value)`.

You might also want to check if the two roots are the same and then only print one.

FYI, there is a `sqrt` function in `math` you can use, but your method of course also works.

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` method reads a line from the input, converts the line into a string by removing the trailing newline, and returns it.

So, the values stored in `a`, `b` and `c` are string. Hence, it is showing the error that you can`t multiply a sequence of string.

```
a, b, c = [int(x) for x in input("Please enter the coefficients (a, b, c): ").split(",")]

disc = float(pow(b*b - 4*a*c,0.5))

root1 = float((-b + disc)/(2 * a))

root2 = float((-b - disc)/(2 * a))

print("The solutions are:" ,root1, root2)
```